# C# WFA login not working using .Split() and reading from .txt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, authentication

I am creating a login screen for the coursework of a quiz game that I have been assigned to make. I am making this quiz in C# (windows form application).

Here is the code before I go any further:

```
entersing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace frmSplashScreen
{
    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        int signUpPressed = 0;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] userdetails = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "UserDetails.txt");
            foreach (string user in userdetails)
            {
                string[] splitDetails = user.Split(':');
                Login.username = splitDetails[0];
                Login.password = splitDetails[1];
                label1.Text = Login.username;
                label2.Text = Login.password;
                if ((txtUsername.Text == Login.username) && (txtPassword.Text == Login.password))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + Login.username);
                    this.Hide();
                    frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu();
                    menu.Show();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((txtUsername.Text == Login.username) && (txtPassword.Text != Login.password))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Password incorrect");
                        txtPassword.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username incorrect");
                        txtUsername.Text = "";
                        txtPassword.Text = "";
                    }
                  break; //Remove this break  it's not needed
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Also here is the .txt file that it is reading the login details from:

```
Ryan:password
Username:password
```

My problem is that when I click the login button(button1), it is only reading the first line of UserDetails.txt, when I type *Ryan* and *password* into the text boxes, it works fine. However, when I type *Username* and *password* into the text boxes it comes up with the error message "Username incorrect" in a Message Box.
Also, 'Login' is a class that stores the variables for username and password

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I formatted your code.. look at the end of your `foreach` loop and I commented showing you want you need to remove.

Comment: these lines need to be refactored, you should separate out your code when trying to create single login form that creates an instance of another form in regards to how you are disposing and or hiding the login form 
`MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + Login.username);
                    this.Hide(); //Not needed 
                    frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu();
                    menu.Show();// change to ShowDialog(); 
                    break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every branch in your foreach loop ends with a `break;`, you never get to the second entry. Move the second break to the "Password incorrect", and allow the loop to continue if the Username does not match, maybe another one does. Check after the loop if a match has been found. (This might be easier when replacing `break;` with `return username;` in a new method `CheckAndGetUser()`.)